# Overriding a function outside its class

Tags: swift, overriding

I came across a strange behaviour. The following code produces a compile error where I call bar() with the message: "Missing argument for parameter #1 call"

```
func bar() {
    println("bar with no argument")
}

class ClassA {

    func bar(varOfAnyType: String) {
        println("bar with argument")
    }

    func foo() {
        bar()
    }
}
```

If I change bar() function's name then I get no errors:

```
func barNameChanged() {
    println("bar with no argument")
}

class ClassA {

    func bar(varOfAnyType: String) {
        println("bar with argument")
    }

    func foo() {
        barNameChanged()
    }
}
```

What's the reason for the compiler not allowing to override the function outside the class?

Cheers, Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, the Swift compiler cannot distinguish between a method and a global function with the same name, regardless of overloading.

The solution is to prefix the global function with its module name, e.g.,

```
func bar() { }

class ClassA {
    func bar(anything: String) {}
    func foo() { Module.bar() }
}
```